# Setting up Heroku for Neo4J

Tags: heroku, neo4j, graphenedb

When I use the command heroku addons create:graphenedb --version v195. It gives error "No app specified , Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use." I am new to Heroku and I do not understand which app folder it is talking about.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not in your project folder or if it doesn't have a git remote to point it to Heroku you need to use the --app flag for the heroku command to specify the name of your app on Heroku

Comment: So I have to create an app on Heroku before I proceed to this step.

Comment: Ah, yes, you would definitely need to do that!  Either with the command `heroku create app-name` (I think your project will need to be a Git repo first), or via the web UI

Comment: After adding my graphenedb_url. It returns a 403 error, why?